# How many keys are the lower grades worth?

Tags: dustforce

If you beat a level with a double 'S' rating, you'll get one key for the harder doors(e.g. silver door levels give gold keys)

When you beat a level with a rating worse than double 'S' you'll basically get a part of a key.

How exactly does that scaling work/what percentage of a key will you receive for which rating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel a bit stupid for answering my own question...

But after some more research on Google, I found [this](http://hitboxteam.com/2012/05/02/mac-version-level-editor-50-off/), where you can scroll down to **New key progression system** you'll find some information, that perfectly answers my question:

> Think of the scores as percentages: an S is worth 50%, an A is worth 40%, all the way down to 10% for a D.  So an SS is worth 100%, an SA is worth 90%, etc.
>   Your top scores in each level are combined to determine your key count: every 100 percentage points you earn, you get a key.  For example, if you get an AB (70%) on one level, and a SA (90%) on another, you get a key, and the 60% remainder is applied to your next key.
>   This works on a per-key-type basis.  So you have a separate meter for silver keys, gold keys, etc.